# How to enable the python to apply custom function faster

Tags: pandas, python-3.x

I have developed a customer function to classify product type in my dataframe.

```
def RST_FINAL_SECOND_FUNCTION(DF_FRAME_NAME):
    if (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column1'] == 'Yes'):
        return 'YES'
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column1'] == 'No'):
        return DF_FRAME_NAME['column2']
df['column3'] = df.apply(RST_FINAL_SECOND_FUNCTION, axis =1)
```

When applying a similar function to a dataset with 200,000 rows consume time, What are the alternative ways to do the above. can we lambda function

Sample Data used for is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes'],
                   'Column2': [5,5,5,7,7,10,10]
                  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np

df['column3'] = np.where(df['Column1'].eq('Yes'), 'Yes', df['Column2'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Column1  Column2 column3
0     Yes        5     Yes
1      No        5       5
2     Yes        5     Yes
3      No        7       7
4      No        7       7
5      No       10      10
6     Yes       10     Yes
```